# Facing issues while developing custom modal using Vue JS library

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue JS. I'm trying to create custom modal using the library VueJS Modal, but modal is not popping up. I have followed the below
https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/blob/master/demo/src/components/Modal_Login.vue
Please point out what am I doing wrong or missing? Please recommend if any alternative library present to achieve custom modal using which I can pass data to function for axios call.

[I want to achieve Modal like this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UywnZ.png)

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
import './assets/css/flex.css'


 Vue.use(VModal) 

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <NavMenu></NavMenu>
    <div class="center">
   
      <br>
      <br>
         <DemoLoginModal></DemoLoginModal>
        <mycomponent></mycomponent>
       
  </div> 
       <br>
       <br>
        <div class="footer">Copyrights &copy;</div>
    
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueGoodTablePlugin from 'vue-good-table';
import NavMenu from '@/components/NavMenu.vue'
import mycomponent  from '@/components/vuejsModal.vue'

 import VModal from 'vue-js-modal'
 import DemoLoginModal from '@/components/vueJSModal2.vue'
import 'vue-good-table/dist/vue-good-table.css'
Vue.use(VueGoodTablePlugin);

  Vue.use(VModal);
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  components: {
    NavMenu, mycomponent,DemoLoginModal
    }
}
</script>

<style>
 .emodal{
     height:550px;
     width:700px;
 }
 
.emodal.osx header{
background:  #0066A1;;
}
.btns{
  opacity: 0;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
  }
.center{
    width: 90%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #232321;
  background: #fff !important;
}
html,
body,
#app{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#app{
  overflow: auto;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

 .footer{

    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    background: #77777b;
    text-align: right;
    width: 99%;
    padding:10px 5px;
    display:block;
    bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #ffffff;

  }

</style>
```

vueJSModal2.vue which has the same code as  https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/blob/master/demo/src/components/Modal_Login.vue

```
<template>
<modal name="demo-login" transition="pop-out" :width="modalWidth" :focus-trap="true" :height="400">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-part" id="bp-left">
      <div class="partition" id="partition-register">
        <div class="partition-title">CREATE ACCOUNT</div>
        <div class="partition-form">
          <form autocomplete="false">

            <div class="autocomplete-fix">
              <input disabled type="password">
            </div>

            <input id="n-email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
            <input id="n-username" type="text" placeholder="Username">
            <input id="n-password2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
          </form>

          <div style="margin-top: 42px">
          </div>

          <div class="button-set">
            <button id="goto-signin-btn" @click="signIn">Sign In</button>
            <button id="register-btn" @click="register">Register</button>
          </div>

          <button class="large-btn github-btn">connect with <span>github</span></button>
          <button class="large-btn facebook-btn">connect with <span>facebook</span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-part" id="bp-right">
      <div class="box-messages">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</modal>
</template>
<script>
const MODAL_WIDTH = 656
export default {
  name: 'DemoLoginModal',
  data() {
    return {
      modalWidth: MODAL_WIDTH
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.modalWidth =
      window.innerWidth < MODAL_WIDTH ? MODAL_WIDTH / 2 : MODAL_WIDTH
  },
  methods: {
    signIn() {
      alert('Sign in')
    },
    register() {
      alert('Register')
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">
$background_color: #404142;
$github_color: #dba226;
$facebook_color: #3880ff;
.box {
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 656px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px black;
  color: #8b8c8d;
  font-size: 0;
  .box-part {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    &#bp-right {
      background: url('/static/panorama.jpg') no-repeat top left;
      border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    }
  }
  .box-messages {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box-error-message {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 0;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 0 12px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: white;
    background: #f38181;
  }
  .partition {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    .partition-title {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding: 30px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    .partition-form {
      padding: 0 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  }
  input[type='password'],
  input[type='text'] {
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 2;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddedf;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-family: inherit;
    transition: 0.5s all;
  }
  button {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    min-width: 140px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    color: #8b8c8d;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid #dddedf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: 0.1s all;
    font-size: 10px;
    &:hover {
      border-color: mix(#dddedf, black, 90%);
      color: mix(#8b8c8d, black, 80%);
    }
  }
  .large-btn {
    width: 100%;
    background: white;
    span {
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    &:hover {
      color: white !important;
    }
  }
  .button-set {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
  #register-btn,
  #signin-btn {
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
  .facebook-btn {
    border-color: $facebook_color;
    color: $facebook_color;
    &:hover {
      border-color: $facebook_color;
      background: $facebook_color;
    }
  }
  .github-btn {
    border-color: $github_color;
    color: $github_color;
    &:hover {
      border-color: $github_color;
      background: $github_color;
    }
  }
  .autocomplete-fix {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
.pop-out-enter-active,
.pop-out-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
.pop-out-enter,
.pop-out-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(24px);
}
</style>
```